# Can Electric Surge Go Through Modem And Fry Laptop?

Tags: power, cable-modem, surge-protection

I have cable internet connection and cable connects to modem. From modem there is a LAN cable connecting to my laptop. Can electric surge reach my laptop?

Comment: A [few](http://superuser.com/questions/31036/what-are-the-chances-a-power-surge-can-wipe-out-a-whole-system-how-can-i-tell) duplicates on that [topic](http://superuser.com/questions/273420/unplug-computer-during-thunderstorms), and another [interesting read](http://www.arcelect.com/lightnin.htm).

Answer (score 6):

Absolutely yes!

Depending on the design, it is highly likely it could take out the modem card rather than the entire machine, but it is still possible and depends entirely on the design of the laptop.

Electricity can run through any cable and fry what is attached.

I had one client who ran indoor grade cable to join buildings together - it got struck by lightning and took out EVERY network port, router and other equipment on the network! Thankfully for most computers, all it took was a cheap network card to fix!

Comment: Is there a way to save modem?

Comment: All I can suggest is purchasing a surge protector or similar for a modem socket, however, I think the chances of this happening are so remote, I would personally live with the risk.

Comment: Yes but what about cable that connects to modem?

Comment: Are you going to answer? Should i wait?

Comment: You need a telephone to telephone cable for port <> ups then you plug your modem like normal to the UPS... most UPSs with a telephone port usually come with them.

Comment: What about cable?

Comment: I don't understand!? It is a telephone port to telephone port cable, as I said, they usually come with the UPS that has this port. In Englad, my UPS has a RJ11 socket, and I can use this sort of cable - http://www.cashgenerator.co.uk/_images/product-details/BE21.jpg - it depends on country.